# Bind ComboBoxItem to ComboBox in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

I should preface this by saying that I am relatively new to working with WPF and bindings. I am trying to bind a ComboBoxItem to a ComboBox inside a DataGridTemplate Column.

As far as I can tell the binding actually does work because the ComboBox inside the DataGrid does contain the objects which I added in the code. The problem I am experiencing is that the SelectedItem is not being displayed when assigned inside the constructor of the object.

I have set up a demo-application in order to reproduce the problem.

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="ComboBoxBindingTests.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ComboBoxBindingTests"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="500">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dg" ItemsSource="{Binding myCollection}" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="200" Header="StringColumn">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding PossibleStrings}" SelectedItem="{Binding SomeString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="22" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="200" Header="ComboBoxItemColumn">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding PossibleComboBoxItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding SomeComboBoxItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="22" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code-Behind**

```
namespace ComboBoxBindingTests
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static ObservableCollection<MyClass> myCollection { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        myCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();

        MyClass t = new MyClass("arb1");
        myCollection.Add(t);
    }
}



public class MyClass
{
    private ObservableCollection<ComboBoxItem> _possibleComboBoxItems;
    public ObservableCollection<ComboBoxItem> PossibleComboBoxItems
    {
        get { return _possibleComboBoxItems; }
        set
        {
            _possibleComboBoxItems = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("PossibleComboBoxItems");
        }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<string> _possibleStrings;
    public ObservableCollection<string> PossibleStrings
    {
        get { return _possibleStrings; }
        set
        {
            _possibleStrings = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("PossibleStrings");
        }
    }
    private ComboBoxItem _someComboBoxItem;
    public ComboBoxItem SomeComboBoxItem
    {
        get { return _someComboBoxItem; }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                ComboBoxItem cbxi = (ComboBoxItem)value;
                _someComboBoxItem = cbxi;
                OnPropertyChanged("SomeComboBoxItem");
            }
        }
    }
    private string _someString;
    public string SomeString
    {
        get { return _someString; }
        set
        {
            if (value.Contains("System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: "))
                _someString = value.Replace("System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: ", "");
            else
                _someString = value;

            OnPropertyChanged("SomeString");
        }
    }

    public MyClass(string chosenString)
    {
        PossibleComboBoxItems = new ObservableCollection<ComboBoxItem>();
        PossibleComboBoxItems.Add(new ComboBoxItem() { Content = "arb1", Height = 20, IsEnabled = true });
        PossibleComboBoxItems.Add(new ComboBoxItem() { Content = "arb2", Height = 20, IsEnabled = true });

        PossibleStrings = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        PossibleStrings.Add("arb1");
        PossibleStrings.Add("arb2");

        SomeString = chosenString;

        if (chosenString != "")
        {
            ComboBoxItem cbxi = new ComboBoxItem();
            cbxi.Content = chosenString;
            cbxi.Height = 20;
            cbxi.IsEnabled = true;
            SomeComboBoxItem = cbxi;                
        }

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler == null) return;
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }        
}
}
```

The reason I want to use a ComboBoxItem instead of just a String is that I need to display objects in the ComboBox which the user cannot select. In my actual software there is a condition that set the IsEnabled-property to false on some objects.

I expected both columns in the DataGrid to show "arb1" as the SelectedItem but only the column which is bound to the string works.
[image: MainWindow showing that only one column displays the SelectedItem]

I have been trying to find a solution for quite some time now and would appreciate it very much if someone could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After consulting a colleague I have finally found the solution.

The lines

```
ComboBoxItem cbxi = new ComboBoxItem();
cbxi.Content = chosenString;
cbxi.Height = 20;
cbxi.IsEnabled = true;
SomeComboBoxItem = cbxi;
```

Need to be replaced with

```
SomeComboBoxItem = PossibleComboBoxItems.SingleOrDefault(x => chosenString == x.Content.ToString());
```